# Show/Hide ToDo-Bar in Outlook with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am not so new to VBA but new to the object model of Outlook VBA. What I currently try, is simply show/hide the To-Do Bar in the E-Mail-View with VBA.

[image]

But I could not find in the object model, where to look and change the visible property.

Did you have a suggestion?

Greetings,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a control ID at the end of the text when hovering over a button to be added to the QAT or a ribbon.

For menu options (and buttons):

- [Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745)
- [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798)

```vb
Option Explicit
'
' Better if a global variable hack could be avoided
'  and the ToDo toggled directly
'  ToDo = Not ToDo
'
' False on startup
'  Applies in this module only
Dim mToDoFlag As Boolean

Sub ToDoToggle()
'
'  Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers
'   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745
'
'  Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers
'   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798
'
'  outlookexplorercontrols.xlsx

'Debug.Print mToDoFlag

If mToDoFlag = False Then
    ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ToDoBarOff")
Else
    ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ToDoBarShowAppointments")
    ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ToDoBarShowContactList")
    ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ToDoBarShowTaskList")
End If

mToDoFlag = Not mToDoFlag

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint where I can find the control ID and how I execute it.

My VBA knowledge is then probably very rusty.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to show/hide the To-Do Bar.

Comment: There is actually, you can still use command bars for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no trivial way to hide the To-Do bar.

But you still can utilize command bars with their `Execute` method to call ribbon controls programmatically. Use the following sequence of calls to find the required control:

```
ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.FindControl(, id-for-the-command-to-run)
```

Then you may call the `Execute` method on that control.

Or just try using [CommandBars.ExecuteMso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.executemso) method passing the `idMso` of the `Off` control. You may find ribbon control identifiers in the [Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745).

Comment: Thanks you  to for the hint where I can find the control ID's.

Comment: I've also posted how you could execute the code required to show/hide the To-Do bar.